# Script for an ATM in Python

Tags: python

I am doing a project for class and can't figure out where I am going wrong. The code works in sections, but when I run it all together it shuts down right after the first input.

I think I need to call functions somewhere - but how and where?

Below is all my code so far, with comments.

```
import sys

#account balance 
account_balance = float(500.25)

##prints current account balance
def printbalance(): 
   print('Your current balance: %2g'% account_balance)

#for deposits 
def deposit(): 
  #user inputs amount to deposit
  deposit_amount = float(input()) 
  #sum of current balance plus deposit
  balance = account_balance + deposit_amount 
  # prints customer deposit amount and balance afterwards
  print('Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is $%2g' %(deposit_amount, 
balance))

#for withdrawals
def withdraw(): 
  #user inputs amount to withdraw
  withdraw_amount = float(input()) 
  #message to display if user attempts to withdraw more than they have
  if(withdraw_amount > account_balance):
    print('$%.2f is greater than your account balance of $%.2f\n' % 
(withdraw_amount, account_balance)) 
  else:
    #current balance minus withdrawal amount
    balance = account_balance - withdraw_amount 
    # prints customer withdrawal amount and balance afterwards
    print('Withdrawal amount was $%.2f, current balance is $%.2f' % 
(withdraw_amount, balance)) 

#system prompt asking the user what they would like to do
userchoice = input ('What would you like to do? D for Deposit, W for 
Withdraw, B for Balance\n')
if (userchoice == 'D'): #deposit
  print('How much would you like to deposit today?')
  deposit()
elif userchoice == 'W': #withdraw
  print ('How much would you like to withdraw today?')
elif userchoice == 'B': #balance
  printbalance()
else:
  print('Thank you for banking with us.')
  sys.exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You just need to move the input prompt and if statements into a while loop so that it asks more than once. At the moment, it will ask once, run the command, then exit when it reaches the end of the script

Answer (score 1):

This part should be as one `userchoice = input ('What would you like to do? D for Deposit, W for Withdraw, B for Balance\n')`

Not sure if you indented by accident, but python does not like that.

Also, advice for your code. Make it so user can either do uppercase or lowercase letters for input, also make sure it still grab input even if user put empty spaces after input string.
 Your withdraw exit the program after entering the string character W.
Balance is not grabbing the correct Deposit.
Use for loops and condition to keep it looping and ask user when to exit.